# Diophantine equation, how many solutions such that $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, diophantine-equations

I've been working on this problem for a while now.
$\text{How many solutions (x, y) above are such that x ≥ 0 and y ≥ 0? for the diophantine equation: }$ $$ 473x + 338y = 4053. $$

I know how to solve diophantine equations so I'll jump to the part where I am unsure.
We get the equation: $473 \cdot ( -5 \cdot 4053) + 338 \cdot ( 7 \cdot 4053) = 4053 $
The general solutions should be $x = -5 \cdot 4053 - 338n$ , $\;n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and

$y = 7 \cdot 4053 + 473n$ , $\,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

lets see where $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$:

$-5 \cdot 4053 - 338n ≥ 0 \implies n ≤ -\frac{5 \cdot 4053}{338} = -59.955...$

$7 \cdot 4053 + 473n ≥ 0 \implies n ≥ -\frac{7 \cdot 4053}{473} = -59.980... $

Thus, $n$ cannot be an integer because there are no integers in the interval $[-59.955.. , -59.980..]$, therefore this Diophantine equation has no solutions for $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$? Is this a correct conclusion?

---

Comment: Here is a [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can format your question better.

Comment: @WillJagy I thought n needed to be a whole number, can you explain what you mean

Comment: @bobeyt6 Thank you, I've update my text now!

Comment: There are just possible eight values for x, each produces a unique, fractional value for y. Why complicate life?

Comment: @OldPeter Forgive me, but could you show what you mean?

Comment: @yunolo Using $y=(4043-473x)/338$, take $x=0$ to give $y=11.9615$. Continue to find $(x,y) = 
(1, 10.56213), 
(2, 9.162721),
(3, 7.763313),
(4, 6.363905),
(5, 4.964497),
(6, 3.565088),
(7, 2.165680),
(8, 0.766272)$
Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @OldPeter aaah yes, of course. You're right, I made it much more complicated than I needed it to be. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OldPeter posted a helpful comment and gave clarity to my question!